# getting properties from other controllers

Tags: ember.js

In the AuthController of my Ember app, I set a currentUser that I can fetch from within the AuthController with

```
this.get('currentUser');
```

from within the AuthController. In another controller, I use `needs: ['auth']` so that I can fetch the currentUser variable from the auth controller, but it's not working. How would I do that?

```
App.BlobController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
     needs: ['auth'],

    actions: {

    doSomething: function() {
       var user;
       user = this.get('currentUser'); /// not working
       $.post(".....
```

Update

Following the instructions in the Ember docs for managing dependencies between controllers http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/, I also tried to do `controllers.auth.get('currentUser');` but it didn't work

```
doSomething: function() {
           var user;
           user = controllers.auth.get('currentUser'); /// not working
           $.post(".....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way it works would be to do it like the following:

```
App.BlobController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['auth'],
  actions: {
    doSomething: function() {
      var user;
      user = this.get('controllers.auth.currentUser');
      $.post("...
```

Or more clean declaring a computed alias on the `BlobController` which refers to the `AuthController` `currentUser` property:

```
App.BlobController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['auth'],
  currentUser: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.auth.currentUser'),
  actions: {
    doSomething: function() {
      var user;
      user = this.get('currentUser');
      $.post("...
```

Hope it helps.